# Counting first and last names appearing more than once

Tags: stata

I have the following names:

```
clear
input str25 names
"Trenton Mercer"
"Carissa Moyer"
"Timothy Delgado"
"Kaylynn Payne"
"Harry Patton"
"Charlie Dudley"
"Harry Schmitt"
"Wyatt Hammond"
"Kasen Delgado"
"Katherine Noble"
"Julius Jarvis"
"Harry Carney"
"Wyatt Holden"
"Megan Wilson"
"Priscilla Shaffer"
"Savanah Marshall"
"Harry Delgado"
"Harper Ballard"
"Harry Mcmahon"
"Alejandro Jarvis"
end
```

How can I identify which first and last names (separately) come up more than once?

I would also like to count how many times these appear.

Answer (score 1):

Pearly's solution (with `split` as the definitely best choice for the issue) appears reasonable. But there are still some unnecessary contours. For example, generating tag, b1, b2 variables seems not really needed.

And more important, the final output is not thoroughly consistent, with the counting info just in line with seemingly-random order, which is also different from the original one without clear explanation.

Thus, I try to contribute a solution (which must also have defects), just as a way to  avoid those issues while still providing the output that you are seeking for.

```
split names

foreach v in `r(varlist)' {
    egen TotalAppear_`v' = total(`v' != ""), by(`v')
    egen LastAppear_`v' = max(_n), by(`v')
    replace LastAppear_`v' = LastAppear_`v'==_n
    list `v' TotalAppear_`v' if LastAppear_`v' == 1 & TotalAppear_`v' >1
}
```

It should be noted your description leads to assumptions made in my code as well as in Pearly's solution:

- Every name has only 2 parts, i.e. first name and last name, so not including any middle name(s).
- You just want to compare within each group (each first name among first names, last name among last names), not comparing any one with those from the other group.

Comment: thanks for your help but i dont really understand what you are doing

Comment: Following the clear instruction in Pearly’s solution, I added the `list` command to give out the visual output. Try my code one more time to see if it could bring about any help. Notice that Pearly’s solution is a good one and both solutions would provide the correct visual output for your needed information, despite their differences in the actual (output) data.

Comment: @user11552543 She is doing the same thing essentially. This is a good example where shorter code is not necessarily the most transparent, which is why on here I usually prefer to show the extra steps and rarely advocate one line solutions. Romalpa is correct that the three variables are not necessary but computationally you will probably not gain much as the `total()` `egen` function pretty much does the same thing under the hood when the `by()` option is used.

Comment: With regards to the final output, what approach is best will depend on what exactly you want to do afterwards. Something you do not tell us. Having the relevant observations in separate variables with the rest missing can be advantageous in several scenarios, especially when you want to export the results. Finally, I also agree with Romalpa's description of the implicit assumptions that need to be done to answer your question and I edited your question to be more clear about this.

Comment: It is a good idea to read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) so you can improve your questions in the future.